# What is the proper way to split a solution of a big mvc application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture, projects-and-solutions

I'm creation an application with over 70 table in database **and it will be increased in the next phases.**

I use Asp.net MVC: **Model, Entity Framework, View Models, Repositories, Views, Controllers, Action Filters, References, Multi languages,....**

**What is the best place for these parts in my solution?**

I have seen different ways to splitting a solution. For example:

```
  - Solution
        - Core.UI
            - Domain
            - UI
               - Models
            - Persistence
        - Core.Test
        - UI
            - Content
            - Controller
            - Views
            - Scripts
```

**Or another says split it to**

```
  - Solution
        - Model
        - Entities
        - Web
        - References
```

**Or**

```
...
```

*What is your opinion about DDD (Domain Driven Design)? and how you implement it? Do you recommend it?*

---

- I want **best flexibility** in my project and **best choice** because
  when a project is big, it will be harder to change its structure.
- I would like to **exchange information in various forms** (Web and html,
  client applications, mobile, xml....)
- I want to change and build fundamental parts of a my project
  **separately** (now and in future)

---

If you could help me with details or examples.

*Thanks a lot...*

Answer (score 3):

The key thing here is that you want to **avoid coupling** so that you can stay productive throughout the development of the app.  In order to do that, you want to do a **Service-Oriented Architecture**.

Instead of n-tier apps which break down the problem into horizontal slices (layers) , 
Service-Oriented Architecture instead takes vertical slices of the application (services).

[Start with this video by Udi Dahan](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/design-architecture/talk-from-udi-dahan) if you want to learn the basic ideas of Service-Oriented Architecture.  Hint: you're starting off on the wrong foot if you've already designed the database.

The two dudes whose stuff you want read here are [Udi Dahan](http://www.udidahan.com/?blog=true) and [Greg Young](http://goodenoughsoftware.net/).  I would also recommend the [DDD Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/dddcqrs) to ask more detailed questions.  DDD questions don't always fit StackOverflow as well as other computing questions because they're so nuanced and usually require a lot of back and forth to get to the bottom of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy answer this question directly. It depends your business needs, scale of your application etc.

There is a reference implementation from Microsoft Spain. Although it has some drawbacks, it is still a good starting point. If you have enough time, just decide which concepts / patterns are needed and which are not.

http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/